# Reorder the Columns in a CSV File in Descending Order

Tags: python, performance, beginner, csv, pandas

I wrote a script to reorder the columns in a CSV file in descending order and then write to another CSV file. My script needs to be able to handle several tens of millions of records, and I would like it to be as performant as possible.

This is basically a mockup of a more complex CSV transformation I would be working on for work (I don't yet know the nature of the transformation I would be performing). To clarify, I was directed to write this at work, and it would be tested/scrutinised to see if its performant enough, but it's also not the final script we would eventually run.

**CSV-Transform.py**

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

chunksize = 10 ** 6 # Or whatever value the memory permits
source_file = ""
# Change to desired source file
destination_file = ""
# Change to desired destination file


def process(chunk, headers, dest):
   df = pd.DataFrame(chunk, columns=headers)
   df.to_csv(dest, header=False,  index=False)


def transform_csv(source_file, destination_file):
   with open(source_file) as infile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
      new_headers = reader.fieldnames[::-1]
   
   with open(destination_file, "w+") as outfile:
      outfile.write(",".join(new_headers))
      outfile.write("\n")

   with open(destination_file, 'a') as outfile:
      for chunk in pd.read_csv(source_file, chunksize=chunksize):
         process(chunk, new_headers, outfile)


transform_csv(source_file, destination_file)
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. `mockup of a more complex CSV transformation I would be working on` does not comply with [actual code from a project rather than … hypothetical code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a *mockup of would-be code* is not the *concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context* required here.

Comment: @greybeard: to clarify, I was directed by my boss to write this mockup first ahead of the task. So it's not just hypothetical code. It is actual code I wrote at work. The script would also be scrutinised to see if its performant enough.

We just don't yet have the schema from our client.

Comment: I have added the elaboration. I don't actually know if this script would be tested against 80 million records, but when my boss mentioned the task of transforming a CSV file of 80 million records, I pitched the approach of using a Pandas dataframe and he asked me to write this mockup first so he could check my approach and see if it would scale.

Comment: If your boss ordered you to make the mock-up, it's still a mock-up. Is it at least a *functional* mock-up? As in, is it actually more a prototype perhaps? "and it would be tested/scrutinised to see if its performant enough" is this something that will eventually be done or has already been done? As in, has this already been tested?